# Laravel 6.2 can't get property of data retrieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6.2

I have a question regarding showing data from my database in Laravel.
I get the following error:

> Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object

It refers to this line of code:

```
 @foreach ($contact as $c)
    <h1 class="display-4">Bekijk details voor contact: {{ $c->first_name }} {{ $c->last_name }}</h1>
 @endforeach
```

I get this data from my database by using Laravel's 'show' function as described below:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $contact = Contact::find($id);

    return view('contacts.show', compact('contact'));
}
```

My routing looks like this:

```
Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactController');
```

The reason I can't get my head wrapped around this error is because it seems to work just fine for other functions like Laravel's 'edit' function as described below:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $contact = Contact::find($id);

    return view('contacts.edit', compact('contact'));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I would like to know why it is not working for my 'show' function whilst it is working for my 'edit' function, are there any differences I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Geert-Jan Knapen

Comment: can you `dd($contact)` for both `show` and `edit`? and show us the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely, `$contact` is the `object` rather than `collection`, so you do not need to loop through it. you can access it directly.

```php
<h1 class="display-4">Bekijk details voor contact: {{ $contact ->first_name }} {{ $contact ->last_name }}</h1>
```

**Update** it's better to use `route model binding`, so it handles if the contact does not exist.

```php
public function show(Contact $contact)
{
    return view('contacts.show', compact('contact'));
}
```

Comment: Yup; `find()` returns a single Record, or `null`. This can still fail if `$contact` is `null`, since `null->first_name` is (obviously) invalid, but you're correct about `Collection` vs instance.

Comment: Nice, looks good! The other option is `findOrFail()`, or a manual check for `$contact`, like `if(!$contact){ abort(404); }` (or similar)

Comment: @TimLewis yeah, a few options.

Comment: Thanks, using `$contact->first_name` does indeed work. What I'm curious about though is that I'm 100% sure $contact is not null, so shouldn't looping through it work in theory?

Comment: @geertjanknapen I think you are confused, the `find`,`route model binding`, `findOrFail()` and other similar methods, only return single recoed. so you do need to loop through it, it's not a `collection`. so you can access it directly.

Comment: @geertjanknapen "I'm 100% sure $contact is not null", the user can still change the url to something else that does not exist on your DB.